# Javascript show image alt on hover using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have many images on my page and I want to display my Images alt on mouse hover using javascript and not jquery

my Images code is

```
<a href="<?php echo $displayData['href']; ?>" class="group">
    <div class="relative">
        <div class="absolute pin bg-black-50 group-hover:bg-black-10 transition"></div>
        <div class="absolute pin-b pin-l h4 pb-2 lg:pb-4 border-b-8 border-primary mb-10 mx-6 text-white z-10 leading-tight">
            <?php echo $displayData['name']; ?>
        </div>
        <img src="<?php echo $displayData['thumb']; ?>" title="<?=$displayData['name']?> alt="<?=$displayData['txt']?>">
    </div>
</a>
```

I used title and alt but both not displaying on mouse hover

Comment: Those behaviors are primarily browser dependent out of the box. I would update your example and make it pure HTML so that others can duplicate your problem 100% accurately. (The PHP code is not relevant to your question)

Comment: Have you checked in your source code whether the title attribute is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the onmouseover and onmouseout events

```
let img=document.querySelector("#imgid");

img.addEventlistener("mouseover",function(e)
{
     e.target.setAttribute('alt','blabla');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**If You Have More images**

```
   <script>
    function set_alt_attribute(image) {

      image.setAttribute("alt", image.src); 
    }
    </script>

    <img src="my_image.jpg" onload="set_alt_attribute(this);">
    </img>
```

**Or single img**

```
document.getElementById("ImageID").title="Dynamic title";
```

Comment: console log show undefined